# How to add additional data in the form and pass it to the POST action method without getting security error

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have an login form where I have div with longitude and lattitude of the user and I would like to pass it to the POST `Login` action method:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })) {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="coordinates"></div> //COORDINATES ARE HERE
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@



            }
        </section>
    </div>
```

Which translates to:

[image]

The action method looks like:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.Email, model.Password);
                if (user != null) {
                    //MY CODE
                    //Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] alternatywnie aby pobrac ip uzytkownika
                    ApplicationUser userSecondInstance = db.Users.Find(user.Id);
                    ApplicationUserAction action = new ApplicationUserAction { Description = "Logged in at " + DateTime.Now + " from IP " + Request.UserHostAddress + ".", TimeStamp = DateTime.Now, Actor = userSecondInstance };
                    db.ApplicationUserActions.Add(action);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //END OF MY CODE
                    await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                } else {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

I would like to pass to the action methods contents of the `<div id="coordinates"></div>`. How to grab them on the server side?

---

**EDIT:**
I have tried that in the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="coordinates" name="coordinates">
```

then

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, string coordinates) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HERE " + coordinates);
```

but unfortunately I get an exception:

```
Wykryto potencjalnie niebezpieczną wartość Request.Form pochodzącą z klienta (coordinates="...52.1372583<br>Longitude: 20.66...").
```

Which means:

```
Potentailly dangerous value of Request.Form has been detected: (coordinates="...52.1372583<br>Longitude: 20.66...").
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any reason not to add them as hidden input fields?

Comment: @Amit No there is not. Please take a look at my edit, I will be ready in 2 mintues.

Comment: @Amit I have tried that but I get security excepiton shown above.

Comment: Not sure where that "potentially dangerous" error is coming from, but there's no reason at all to pass "<br>" as part of your values. Use multiple input elements and have a single, meaningful value in each one.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know asp.net

Nevertheless you can make use of Hidden input elements inside the form.
in pure html format:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Longitude" value="12.22323231">
<input type="hidden" name="Lattitude" value="77.11235813">
```

Hope this helps. Else comment, I will delete the answer

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot but unfortunately I get an exception seen above.

Comment: i am amazed! why do coordinates has all the <br> and all? Typicall in form submit, you should get value pairs.. like Lattitude="12.21212"&Longitude="53.1211"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create a properties for `Latitude`, `Longitude`, and `Accuracy` in `LoginViewModel`. Then, use `Html.HiddenFor` to render it. It will automatically post and bind it to `LoginViewModel`

Edit:

View Model:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public string Email {get; set;}
    ...
    public double Latitude {get; set;}
    public double Longitude {get; set;}
    public double Accuracy {get; set;}

}
```

View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" })) {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="coordinates">
            @*Include these*@
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Latitude)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Longitude)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Accuracy)
        </div> //COORDINATES ARE HERE
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@



            }
        </section>
    </div>
```

Controller Action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl) 
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: What I should write in `Login` parametrer list?`(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, Double latitude, Double longitude, Double accuracy)`?

Comment: Thanks. That's wise. I must leave, I'll try as soon as I get to home.

Comment: Thanks for this solution what are advantages of this solution over having list parameter: `(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl, Double latitude, Double longitude, Double accuracy)`? Your solution looks more mature, but what are other advantages? I overcame the yellow screen of death by removing the `<br>` from the input fields. ASP didn't like the html keywords passed by form.

Comment: This is where ViewModel comes into play. You can easily render properties using just `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Property)`. Otherwise you have to send it through `ViewBag/ViewData`.

Comment: If you want to pass html through the form, you can use `[AllowHtml]` attribute. Or you can also use `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute in controller action to disable request validation for every fields. You cannot put html because you have `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in web.config.

Comment: Thanks, my question is(and how) is your solution better from technical standpoint? It looks much better.

Comment: By doing like this you are getting advantages of automatic model binding from asp.net mvc. Your can pass data easily to the view and get data easily. You can put different validation in the model itself and asp.net mvc will automatically validate your inputs.